# Unable to add any validations in single resource model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to create a very simple social network. I started with two models: User (using Devise gem) and his Profile. They are connected by 1-to-1 relationship, so my routes look like:

```
resources :users do
    resource :profile
end
```

I have an appropriate controller - here's the code for creating profile (editing is pretty much the same):

```
def new
    @profile = current_user.create_profile
end

def create
    @profile = current_user.profile.create(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
    else
        render :action => "new"
    end
end
```

I used current_user variable, because user is not allowed to create profile for someone else, no matter what he types in the address bar.

In the 'new' view I've got a form:

```
- form_for [@profile.user, @profile] do |p|
    (fields omitted)
```

It's working just as I expected - users can add their data to profiles and after hitting "Save" are redirected to their newly created page. However, when I try to add some validations to Profile model (even simple ones, like **validates_presence_of**) and then create new profile, my controller shows me an error:

```
undefined method `user_profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0xb2d3e5c>:0xb2d2728>

Extracted source (around line #1):
1: - form_for [@profile.user, @profile] do |p|
```

It's strange, but this problem does not occur at updating profile informations, only while trying to create new one. I googled a solution telling me to specify redirect url in form_for helper. So, I changed it in my view:

```
- form_for [@profile.user, @profile], :url => user_profile_path(@profile.user) do |p|
```

It still doesn't work. It displays the view I wanted (with a validation error message right from the start, but I could live with that ;-)), but after hitting "Save" it produces another problem:

```
undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass
```

I find it even more strange, as it displays parameter object in error details, it contains the right data and is everything but not nil. I ran out of ideas, what can be wrong.

I'm a little bit curious. What is causing my problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try not to ask one question at the time please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@profile = current_user.create_profile(params[:profile])
```

In your create action - instead of .profile.create

Comment: It still keeps saying "undefined method for nil", only this time it cannot find 'create_profile'.

Comment: Well in that case it sounds like current_user is nil!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

```
# user.rb
  def initialize(*params)
    super(*params)
    self.build_profile unless self.profile
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
Make sure there is a current_user, require the user to be logged in.

Second:
You are getting the user_profiles_path method on new because the profile is not persisted. The url generation method in rails will pluralize in that case. If you want the correct url all the time use: `[@profile.user, :profile]`. You can do this, as there is only one profile per user, and there is no need for the profile id.

Third: 
In your create action, replace

```
@profile = current_user.profile.create(params[:profile])
# with 
@profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
```

Last: 
Consider not having a difference between creating and editing the profile. For your end user it won't make any difference. You can add in a before filter the creation of an empty profile, in case it is missing. It will also be less code for you. to maintain